# What's the difference between these two sentences? Are they both correct?

Tags: american-english

Peter **has lived** in this city since he was born.

Peter **has been living** in this city since he was born.

Comment: There's no difference in meaning (except in unusual / contrived contexts), but [the simpler verb form is ***much*** more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+lived+there+since%2Chas+been+living+there+since&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20lived%20there%20since%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20been%20living%20there%20since%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @ FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica Can you explain why the simpler form is more common?